# Center title in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Simple question here: Is it possible to center title in R Markdown by specifying another argument in the YAML? Or is there another way to do this? I've been having trouble finding a solution online. I've used Latex quite a lot and comfortable in it, is there a \maketitle{} option/argument that can be used in R-markdown?

Here is an example of my code and what I've tried to do:

```
---
\begin{center}
title: "Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
\end{center}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
header-includes: \usepackage{fancyhdr}
fig_caption: yes
css: reportstyles.css
urlcolor: blue
---
```

Comment: Hey thanks, just saw that I'll remove my question I think they answered it for me

Comment: No worries glad it helps answer your question.